# how to get the hierarchical dat using recursive in php with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

the below function has recursive function for organizational chart;
family_user table:

```
function getrel($userid)
{

      $sql =  'SELECT DISTINCT *  FROM family_user WHERE userid in ( SELECT  DISTINCT rel_id FROM family_rel WHERE tree_id ='.$userid.')';

       $query = $this->db->query($sql);                                        
       if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
       {
            foreach($query->result_array() as $row)

            {
                $user[] = $row['userid'];
                if(@in_array($row['userid'],$user))
                {
                    echo "---------->";
                    echo $row['userid'];
                    echo "</br>";                            
                    $this->getrel($row['userid']);        
                    //echo "HAI";                                            
                }                                           
            }                 
           // return $user;                                                         
       }
}
```

the above function has no limit.please resolved

Comment: please give more details and be specific on your question thanks.

Comment: `if(@in_array($row['userid'],$user))` $row['userid'] is not an array!

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is going to be in an infinite loop when ever the userid provide while calling the function matches in the database.

To break a recursive loop there should be a condition which exits the loop after a finite number of run.

To provide you a good solution please elaborate what you would like to achieve with your code.